# Number theory equation

Tags: number-theory

I need to answer this question from my maths course:
Let $x, y$ and $z$ be integers, find all the triplets $(x, y, z)$ that satisfy this equation.

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - xy - yz - xz = 3$

What I tried is multiplying by 2.
Wie have
$2x^2 + 2y^2 + 2z^2 - 2xy - 2yz - 2xz = 6$
$x^2 + x^2 + y^2 + y^2 + z^2 +z^2 - 2xy - 2yz - 2xz = 6$

Because of the binomial formulas, we get now
$(x-y)^2 + (y-z)^2 + (z-x)^2 = 6$

So now I have to find three square numbers that added get 6. I know by intuition it would be 4, 1 and 1, even though I can not go on with the equation and build the systems of equations in order to solve it.
An idea would be
$x-y=2 or 1 or -1 or -2$
$y-z=1 or 2 or -1 or -2$
$z-x=1 or 2 or -1 or -2$

Could someone help me out?